# How to install OpenCV 3.4.5 in Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: opencv, ubuntu-14.04

I am trying to install OpenCV 3.4.5 in Ubuntu 14.04 LTS and I need this OS for my project. I have not found any proper way to do so. I tried this: https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.5/d2/de6/tutorial_py_setup_in_ubuntu.html but cannot install the dependencies as mentioned.

Any suggestions or guide would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have Python installed, try install [opencv-python](https://pypi.org/project/opencv-python/#description) which is an unofficial pre-built OpenCV package.

```
pip install numpy
pip install opencv-python==3.4.5
```

To ensure successful installation, open IDLE to check version number:

```
import cv2
print(cv2.__version__)
```